# Catching SIGTERM, and sleep preventing it working

Tags: c, sigterm

I have some code written in C (working on ubuntu 17):

```
void sig_stop(int sig_num) {
    /* Some cleanup that needs to be done */
}

void some_routine(const char *array[], const int length) {
    /* Initialization */
    signal(SIGTERM, sig_stop);

    while (true) {
        /* Some function */

        /* I have this sleep to minimize the load on the CPU 
            as I don't need to check the conditions here 
            all the time. */
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Whenever I include the 5 minute sleep (`sleep(5)`), it appears `sig_stop` isn't called. However, when I comment out the `sleep(5)`, the `sig_stop` cleanup works just fine. Have I got something wrong with my understanding of how to catch `SIGTERM`?

If I can't use the `sleep` function, is there a better way to "sleep" the program" so that it only runs the loop every x minutes or in such a way that minimizes the CPU load?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `sleep()` and signals

`sleep()` should not prevent the signal from being caught and the signal handler being executed. From the [manpage for `sleep()`](https://man.cx/sleep(3)) (emphasis mine):

> sleep() causes the calling thread to sleep either until the number of real-time seconds specified in seconds have elapsed or **until a signal arrives which is not ignored**.

Take the following example ...

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;

static void sig_stop(int signum) { flag = 1; }

int main(void) {
    int secs_remaining = 0;
    signal(SIGTERM, sig_stop);

    while (!flag) {
        printf("Sleeping at time %d\n", time(NULL));
        secs_remaining = sleep(5);
    }
    printf(
        "Flag raised. Exiting at time %d. sleep() was interrupted %d seconds "
        "early ...\n",
        time(NULL), secs_remaining);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that - in the case where it was interrupted by a signal - `sleep()` returns the number of seconds left to sleep. E.g., if it is interrupted 3 seconds early it will return `3`. It will return `0` if it is not interrupted.

Compile as `gcc -o test test.c` and run. Then from another terminal run

```
pkill -15 test
```

You will see output similar to the following ...

> Sleeping at time 1532273709
>   Flag raised. Exiting at time 1532273711. sleep() was interrupted 2 seconds early ...

By the way ... `sleep(x)` sleeps for `x` *seconds* - not minutes.

#### `signal()` vs `sigaction()`

Due to portability issues associated with `signal()`, it is often recommended to use `sigaction()` instead. The use of `sigaction()` would be something like the following.

```
int main(void) {
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = sig_stop;
    if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }
    // Etc.
}
```

As you can see the usage of `sigaction()` is a little more verbose than that of `signal()`. Perhaps that's why people still sometimes use `signal()`.

Comment: My apologies for the sleep mistake, stupid error. I can run your test.c perfectly and it behaves like you said (and makes a lot of sense). However when I attempt the same pkill -15 on my own program it presents the msg: "pkill: killing pid 45 failed: Operation not permitted", and with sudo prefix, it executes, but doesn't kill the program.

Comment: @Athena: SIGTERM will indeed usually terminate a program. However, when you use `signal()` to install a custom signal handler, the default behaviour is overriden. If you want to exit the program, you need to set a flag / variable in your signal handler and monitor that in your `while()` loop.

Comment: After I changed my `while(true)` condition, to `while(!flag)`, as you recommended, it's working perfectly.

Comment: @Athena: Cool. Also ... I updated my answer with a mention of `sigaction()` (which is a recommended alternative to `signal()`.)

Comment: @Athena Given `static int flag;`, `while (!flag)` will not necessarily "see" the change to `flag=1` in `static void sig_stop(int signum) { flag = 1; }`.  Any compiler would be free to convert `while(!flag)...` to an infinite loop since `flag` starts with the value `0` and never changes value in `main`.  `flag` needs to be `volatile` in this case - or better yet, `sig_atomic_t`.  See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14